# Creating Matrix from instance variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, matrix

The following command

```
@offers = Matrix[]
allotment_matrix = Matrix[@proposal, @facility, @price.to_i, @keywords]
@offers = @offers.vstack(allotment_matrix)
```

yields data as `34, 40, #<BigDecimal:7fb1339a5420,'0.38E3',9(18)>, " Near train station`"` and then processes with error:

```
TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into an Array (undefined method `to_ary' for 32:Fixnum
```

when the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-c-vstack) states

```
x = Matrix[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
y = Matrix[[5, 6], [7, 8]]
Matrix.vstack(x, y) # => Matrix[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

I fail to see how I can create a Matrix

Comment: `[]` method on Matrix class expect each argument to be an array.
Check [this](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-c-5B-5D). 
Where as you are passing non array values to the method. Try below to get
 this working
`allotment_matrix = Matrix[[@proposal], [@facility], [@price.to_i], [@keywords]]`

Comment: Why do you want to use `Matrix` to store a vector (`Array` in ruby terms) in the first place?

Comment: @mudasobwa  I failed to assert that I was going to use vstack. @Ankush, that was a proper syntax; it went and created the Matrix. which leads to the error `The given matrices must have 0 columns, but one has 1` what else may I be missing?

Comment: Can you please share the values of all the instance variables here to understand the issue better?

Comment: I updated question to reflect the generated data